# How do I create annotations for functions?

Tags: front-end, customization

In 10.3, Mathematica starts captioning symbol-names into foreign languages if your Interface preferences are set to have Mathematica in a foreign language.

[image: Graph annotated]

I poked around the `Attributes`, and viewed the `Cell` expression, but from the code I couldn't find any sign that this was happening at all (though it's obviously happening somehow).

I want to be able to make this happen on my own functions: to be able to supply translations, for instance, or extremely short inline explanations. For example, if I made a little function `toInt`, I might want to attach a type annotation `String->Integer`. This could help offset the verbosity of Mathematica code by making the notebook interface that little bit more intelligent.

One can see the translations available using `WolframLanguageData`:

```
WolframLanguageData[Graph][
 EntityProperty["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Translations"]
]
```

How does Mathematica do the translation annotations, and how can I do it myself?

Comment: +1 I would really like to know the answer too!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Edit

[Karsten 7.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18476/karsten-7) suggested a better method in the comments, which does not require a modification of any system files and can be used under English language setting. It works on my 10.2 installation after applying the following procedures:

1. Under the user's directory (`FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory,"SystemFiles\\FrontEnd\\SystemResources\\FunctionalFrequency"}]`), add a file named, say, **CustomAnnotation.m**.
2. Edit this **CustomAnnotation.m** as you want, consisting with the format of the built-in language specification file as described in my old answer (see below).
3. Either open the Option Inspector and add the following path to **Global Options ► File Locations ► PrivatePaths ► "TranslationData"**:

   > ```
   > FrontEnd`FileName[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "SystemResources", "FunctionalFrequency"}]
   > ```

   or execute the following code within the notebook:

   ```
   CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {PrivatePaths, "TranslationData"}] = 
    Append[CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {PrivatePaths, "TranslationData"}], 
      FrontEnd`FileName[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
        "SystemResources", "FunctionalFrequency"}]];
   ```
4. Restart *Mathematica*.
5. Execute the following code in *Mathematica* (replace `$FrontEnd` with `$FrontEndSession` for non-persistent modification):

   ```
   SetOptions[$FrontEnd, TranslationOptions -> {"Enabled" -> True, 
                                                "Language" -> "CustomAnnotation"}]
   ```

---

## Original Answer

**NOTE:**

1. The following method works on my Mathematica 10.2, but not tested on other versions. [Also tested on Mathematica 10.3, Mac OS 10.11.1.]
2. The following method involving modification of a system file, **thus is likely prohibited by the EULA**.

---

1. First find the language specific file located on a path similar to the following (I will use the simplified Chinese as a demonstration):

   > C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.2\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\SystemResources\FunctionalFrequency\ChineseSimplified.m
2. Add a new function annotation line (the 3rd line in the snapshot):

   [image: Mathematica graphics]
3. Open Mathematica with language setting to simplified Chinese, type `ThisIsATestFunction` in a notebook:

   [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is great - I'd still like a way to do this without changing the system language, but that's looking increasingly unlikely given how it seems to have been implemented.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I doubt there is any way without changing system files..

Comment: @Karsten7. I would like to know how to make it work under english language settings.

Comment: @Karsten7. I edited your method in my answer, please feel free to correct me if there is any misunderstanding.

Comment: This method seems to be limited to function names starting with a capital letter or $, though.

Comment: @Karsten7. Indeed. I guess functions starting with a lowercase letter might be filtered out internally.