# How to turn on/off foreign-language symbol explanation by executing a command?

Tags: front-end, customization

How to turn on/off foreign-language symbol explanation by executing a command?

Trying to do it by using menu "Mathematica > Preferences > Interface > click the checkbox" in front of "Show code caption" caused my Mathematica front-end to hang with a macOS progressing indicator that never finishes.

Comment: at least closely related: [**97290**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97290/5478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {TranslationOptions, "Enabled"}] = True;
```

You can skip this line but if you want to change the default captions language:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {TranslationOptions, "Language"}] = "Polish";
```

Comment: I'd appreciate that you also explain the fishing -- how to find the command but not only provide the fish.

Comment: @qazwsx so the rod is, if something can be changed via preferences dialog it is probably in `Options[$FrontEnd]` or in `Options[$DefaultFrontEnd]`. Then I searched for `Translation` keyword via Crtl+F ;)

Comment: That exactly what should be added in a good and complete answer.

Comment: @qazwsx Look at Format -> Option Inspector.  Set the first dropdown to Global. *All* the front end settings are there, and they can be set programmatically using `CurrentValue`.

Comment: I knew that menu option, but at that time, when I tried, the front-end froze and gave me a never ending macOS progress wheel.